# What causes a wordpress homepage to load

Tags: php, wordpress

UPDATE: Real links below to illustrate my issue.
Stick with me on this, because it is a valid question.

In the old days I could have danhoover.org which was a wordpress site and I could have danhoover.org/new which was another wordpress site and both would load fine. I could even point danhoover.net to the danhoover/new directory and the page would load just fine no matter how you got there.  You could use danhoover.org/new or danhoover.net and it would load fine.  All the permalinks would work. No problem.

Now, however, there is some sort of voodo going on.  If a wordpress site is in the danhoover.org/new folder and configured to be "danhoover.net", navigating to the folder as danhoover.org/new will just get you a 404 error.

In addition, going to danhoover.org/new/index.php will get you a 404 error.

There is some sort of voodoo going on that makes you use the url defined in the configuration for the site to work properly.  What is it? Is there any way to manually update the permalink structure so it loads properly with either domain?

I guess I'm just confused as to what in the world wordpress is doing that is different than any other php site that prevents it from loading.

UPDATED LINKS:
I have a folder /a which has [campscoreboard.net](http://campscoreboard.net) pointed to it.
I have a folder /a/c which has [www.c.campscoreboard.net](http://www.c.campscoreboard.net) pointed to it.

Wordpress links:
You can go to [www.campscoreboard.net/c](http://www.campscoreboard.net/c) and the homepage loads
You can go to [www.c.campscoreboard.net](http://www.c.campscoreboard.net) and the homepage loads and all
the links work.
But if you go to [www.campscoreboard.net/c](http://www.campscoreboard.net/c) and click on a link like the
Hello World article, you're redirected back to the root for some
reason.

Vanilla PHP Links
You can go to [www.campscoreboard.net/c/test.php](http://www.campscoreboard.net/c/test.php) and it loads fine.
You can go to [www.c.campscoreboard.net/test.php](http://www.c.campscoreboard.net/test.php) and it loads fine.

Only the wordpress urls are redirecting back to the root when loaded via [www.campscoreboard.net/c](http://www.campscoreboard.net/c)

Comment: Sounds like an .htaccess or server config issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried to install WordPress inside WordPress before, but ...

In the `wp-config.php` file of the relevant WordPress installation, you can set the correct URL and HOME directory manually using:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://danhoover.org/new/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://danhoover.org/new/' );
```

I usually add these after `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I've gotten it really close with wp home as danhoover.org/new and siteurl as danhoover,net.  That's the closest I can get to working.  Everything works EXCEPT when I go to danhoover.org/new the site loads but if I click on any links I'm redirected to back to the document root.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be related to the home configuration as all that would do is forward you to danhoover.org, not give you a 404.

This is likely a server permissions issue where your server is blocking access to the folders. This can be set either on the servers main config file (e.g. httpd.conf) or in a .htaccess file which can be placed in any folder to which one wishes to change its (/subfolders') permissions.
You can read some more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess_for_subdirectories).

A quick way to help you diagnose this, create a static html file and place it in danhoover.org/new call it index.html and place some text in the file then load danhoover.org/new in your browser and see if the text you've written in the file appears, if not then you know it's a server/permissions issue, not a Wordpress one.

Comment: I will edit the question so you can check out the actual links.

Comment: It appears that the links for both http://www.c.campscoreboard.net/ and http://www.campscoreboard.net/c do not work. Do you have a separate database for each instance of Wordpress?